# MySQL syntax error - Java Bukkit / Spigot plugin

Tags: java, mysql, syntax, bukkit

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to connect my Java Plugin to the local MySQL database:

```
[01:15:44 INFO]: [BetterStaff] Could not connect to database:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Reportslog' ('SenderName' varchar(32), 'Message' string)' at line 1
```

The code from my plugin is:

```
    this.db.openConnection();
    Statement statement = this.db.getConnection().createStatement();
    statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'Reportslog' ('SenderName' varchar(32), 'Message' string)");
```

Can you help me or correct my SQL syntax please?

Comment: Remove the ' from your code.

Comment: Should I remove all '? Something like this:  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Reportslog (SenderName varchar(32), Message string)" ?

Comment: Yes, the only reason to use quotes is when you assign labels (for people who want to have spaces in their table or column names).

Comment: also there is no ['string'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-types.html) type

Comment: What should I type to replace something like 'string' type in Java. I'm just going through MySQL only if it's a must, I don't know much about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes are not allowed in the table name or fields:

```
String sql = 
   "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Reportslog (SenderName varchar(32), Message varchar(32))";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my last few hours. :))

Comment: What means "conn" from PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

Comment: its a `java.sql.Connection` instance, same as `db.getConnection()` in your case